# How can I reach the hidden ladder in Hinterlands

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I was now able to defeate the dragon in the Hinterlands. When I explored the area I found a ladder. (See Screenshots) But I have no idea how to get there.

Is there a way to access the ladder?

[image: Ladder]
[image: Location on the map]

Comment: That one is driving me crazy. First I spent good 5-10 minutes to locate the source of the ping, than another half an hour to try to get to the ladder with no success.

Comment: Drove me nuts too trying to get to the cranes and collapsed dock area...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured this one out. I think it just has to do with cranes or whatever those structures are, because the one to the right of the one in your screen shot also has a ladder in the same spot, only the one in the screen shot is "collapsed" and the ladder has clipped through the wall.

Comment: This explanation sounds reasonable.